# Easy Way to Revisit and Edit Own Documents Under Review

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation, revision-history

Currently when you visit a topic you cannot see that examples and content you have submitted for review. If you can easily navigate to this one can improve and correct the submission until someone actually review it. Also you can deal with accidental submissions. Also you know what is under review and the content was not lost due to some submission error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to this link to view your pending proposed changes:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=documentation&sort=proposedchanges

As of this writing, you do **not** have any proposed changes, so there aren’t any to view.